# Mac Laravel file_put_content fail permission problem

Tags: laravel

I have a project work in laravel (Mac) but I have a problem:

> file_put_content fail () Permission denied.

I try below command

```
cd /path to htdocs
sudo chgrp -R _www storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

but it's not working
anyone know how to solve this problem. I use XAMPP, is that possible to set my XAMPP htdocs folder permission read&write, so I don't need to worry about this anymore

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's coming from cache. Delete **bootstrap** > **cache** > **config.php** file.

Then use `php artisan config:cache`.

Comment: Have you deleted config.php from  bootstrap folder?

Comment: sudo chmod -R  777 bootstrap try with this.

Comment: i did -R 777 same result

Comment: give 777 permission to storage and bootstrap both folder and check it. then delete bootstrap > cache > config.php file. and clear cache using `php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 1):

you need to provide write access to your storage folder too.
try running :

**sudo chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap**

It will provide read & write and execute permissions to both storage and bootstap folder.